# '$ionicScroll', required by directive ERROR IN IONIC

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

I make simple example of ng-repeat  when I used ng-repeat it works fine .But when I use collection-repeat it gives me this error

> Controller '$ionicScroll', required by directive 'collectionRepeat', can't be found!

could you please help me solving this error

Here is my my plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/LjADQj07M4cEpTQP3WzS?p=preview

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Invoices Grid</title>
    <!--Stylesheets-->
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Scripts-->
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="a">
  <div class="row" collection-repeat="n in names">
    <div class="col">{{n.name}}</div>
     <div class="col">{{n.lasename}}</div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First post Google post : 
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-compile-ctreq-controller-ionicscroll-required-by-directive-collectionrepeat-cant-be-found/4879

collection repeat needs a scrolling system.
Therefore, suround your code with   `<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" >`

See updated plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/LuHPy3lbqYBlg35iYuw1?p=preview